# How can we calculate the number of changes across the number of columns?

Tags: excel, vba

Here is my dataset.

```
date    3/1/2023    3/2/2023    3/3/2023    3/4/2023    3/5/2023    3/6/2023    3/7/2023    3/8/2023    3/9/2023    3/10/2023   3/11/2023   3/12/2023
symbol                                              
AAPL    3   4   1   4   0   0   0   1   2   3   1   1
AMGN    0   2   2   4   0   4   3   1   2   0   0   2
AXP     2   0   0   0   1   1   1   3   1   1   0   2
BA      2   2   0   4   2   4   4   0   0   4   0   2
CAT     2   3   4   3   1   1   1   3   1   1   4   0
```

I am trying to find a way to calculate the number of changes per date. For example, AAPL, changes 8 times. The 0 to 0 to 0 is not a change and the 1 to 1 is not a change. Otherwise, across 12 dates, I see 8 changes. How can I generate this calculation? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Copy the formula at N2 in my example, press CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER
because is an array formula and dragging down

```vb
=SUM((B2:L2<>C2:M2)*1)

OR

=SUM(--(B2:L2<>C2:M2))
```

According to @bugdrown's comment it can be written using SUMPRODUCT instead of SUB, without needing to press CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER

```vb
=SUMPRODUCT((B2:L2<>C2:M2)*1)

OR

=SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:L2<>C2:M2))
```

Comment: Should also be able to use `SUMPRODUCT()` without C+S+E.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the counts are in `B3:M7`:

```
=BYROW(
    B3:M7,
    LAMBDA(φ, LET(κ, DROP(φ, , 1), λ, DROP(φ, , -1), SUM(N(κ <> λ))))
)
```